# grid.table plots: Setting cell background color based on row values

Tags: r

I'm using `grid.table()` to print a dataframe as a plot. I would like to fill the cells with the color contained in each row as an hex code.

Below is a sample of the rows I am working with.

```
df    
1 "#FFB325" "#000000" "#FFFFFF" "#00080"  
2 "#000000" "#000080" "#FFB325" "#FFFFFF"
```

I tried grid.table(as.color(df)) to print a plot.  Grid.table gives me what I want except without the color coded cells.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Cells of what output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot colors with hex values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867716/plot-colors-with-hex-values-in-r)

Comment: `df` is an R `data.frame` object. *Where* do you want to colour cells? In an RMarkdown document? Using a specific package? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps OP is using RStudio and wants the `View(df)` function to display coloured cells in the viewing pane. (Note: this isn't possible.) If this is the case, then I recommend you explore R and RStudio further to learn more about what the two are and what their typical usages might be.

Comment: I was using grid.table(df) to make a table, and would like each cell that is in the grid table to be the corresponding color to the number in the cell

Comment: @DanY That is my end goal, but with the colors I have in the cells and not a specific color palette.

Comment: Can you list which packages you are using?  I assume `grid.table` is from the `gridExtra` package, but a few packages have functions named `as.color` and I'm not sure which one you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to choose the background color for each cell, define a color set and then apply it using a custom theme.

Try something like this:

```
color_df <- data.frame(color = c("#FFB325", "#00EE00", "#FFFFFF", "#008080", 
                                 "#00EE00", "#008080", "#FFB325", "#FFFFFF"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


my_table_theme <- ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = color_df$color, col=NA)))

grid.table(color_df, theme = my_table_theme)
```

[image]

To show multiple columns, each with different colors, create a separate theme for each column and then display them all together with `grid.arrange()`:

```
color_df <- data.frame(blues = c("#F7FBFF", "#DEEBF7", "#C6DBEF", "#9ECAE1", "#6BAED6", "#4292C6", 
                                 "#2171B5", "#084594"),
                       greens = c("#F7FCF5", "#E5F5E0", "#C7E9C0", "#A1D99B", "#74C476", "#41AB5D", 
                                  "#238B45", "#005A32"),
                       spectral = c("#D53E4F", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#E6F598", "#ABDDA4", 
                                    "#66C2A5", "#3288BD"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


table_theme_blues <- ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = color_df$blues, col=NA)))
table_theme_greens <- ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = color_df$greens, col=NA)))
table_theme_spectral <- ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = color_df$spectral, col=NA)))

grid.arrange(
    tableGrob(color_df["blues"], theme=table_theme_blues, rows = NULL),
    tableGrob(color_df["greens"], theme=table_theme_greens, rows = NULL),
    tableGrob(color_df["spectral"], theme=table_theme_spectral, rows = NULL),
    nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much!! Is there a way to do it with multiple columns and rows? When I try adding more colors and applying it to the df, it comes out with the same color for each row, keeping the number of colors that matches the number of rows in my df @HAVB

Comment: @user10256905 no problem. If the answer solved your issue, you may consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to it -it will be useful for future visitors to know that the solution was tested and it worked